# How can I take data from excel and put it in my application with AutoIT?

Tags: excel, autoit

I should take data from an existing Excel file and put it in my application with auto it.

Comment: Can you be more specific in terms of the application, an example of the data, and how you'd like it to be handled.

Comment: yes, should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Stackoverflow is not a scriptgenerator, show us what you tried and we could help you.

You could use the Excel Library, with the following commands.

```
#include <Excel.au3>
```

[_Excel_Open](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_Open.htm)

[_Excel_BookOpen](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_BookOpen.htm)

[_Excel_RangeRead](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_RangeRead.htm)

And I need more information about that application, if you need tipps for inserting data.